# _tkinter.TclError: unknown color name "systemWindowBody"

Tags: python, tkinter, overlay

I wanted to make a simple overlay reacting to buttons with python, so I downloaded pypi overlay module and pasted their code to run a simple test overlay. Unfortunately, even this doesn't work, because it throws an error mentioned in the title.

Code:

```
from overlay import Window
win = Window()
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\zer0v\Desktop\Python\Hakej's Overlay\dbd_overlay.py", line 3, in <module>
    win = Window()
  File "C:\Users\zer0v\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\overlay\window.py", line 42, in __init__
    self.transparent = kwargs.get('transparent', False)
  File "C:\Users\zer0v\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\overlay\window.py", line 125, in transparent
    self._root.config(bg=bg)
  File "C:\Users\zer0v\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1485, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\zer0v\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1476, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown color name "systemWindowBody"
```

I have searched for this problem and somebody had a similiar issue, but with a matplotlib and plot instead. They mentioned something about .Xresources, but I have no idea what and where it is, and I cannot find anything useful about it in the Internet. I'm probably missing something, but I'm running out of ideas, so that's why I'm making this post.

Comment: The color 'systemWindowBody' is available in Mac OS.  As stated in its PyPi page, the code is not tested in other platforms.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you're right. If you'd put that comment as an answer I would tag it. :)